# HTTP REQUEST consumed or not?

Tags: java, http, httprequest, httpresponse

I have a requirement in java in which i need to create a HTTP request service to post content to some other service. The consuming service uses the data from the HTTP Request. 
The problem which i am facing is that sometimes the consuming service gets some errors and it does not return any response back to HTTP Service.

The HTTP Request service catches the status code of Response to know that the Request went through. When i do not get response back , is there any way to know the HTTP Request went through. I need to validate my HTTP request for 4xx(e.g. 404) status codes. Here is the JAVA function which is am using to do a HTTP POST

```
public boolean postStringXMLContentToUrl(String content,
        String mimetype, String charset, String url) {

    boolean isContentPosted = true;
    BufferedReader br = null;

    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

    HttpResponse httpResponse;
    try {
        ContentType contentType = ContentType.create(mimetype, charset);
        StringEntity StringContentEntity = new StringEntity(
                content, contentType);
        post.setEntity(StringContentEntity);
        httpResponse = client.execute(post);
        int returnCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        log.info("Status Code = "+returnCode);
        if (returnCode == HttpStatus.SC_NOT_IMPLEMENTED) {
            log.warn("The Post method is not implemented by this URI");
            isContentPosted = false;
        }
        else if(returnCode == HttpStatus.SC_NOT_FOUND)
        {
            log.warn("Service not found ");
            isContentPosted = false;
        }
        else {
            if(new String(new Integer(returnCode).toString()).matches("2[0-9][0-9]")) //Status code 2xx for e.g. 200, 201 etc
            {
                isContentPosted = true;
                log.info("HTTP POST request sent successfully to"+url+" with content \n" + content);
            }
            else
            {
                isContentPosted = false;
                log.info("HTTP POST request unsuccessfull to"+url);
            }
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));
            String readLine;        
            log.info("Response from HTTP POST to " + url);
            while (((readLine = br.readLine()) != null)) {
                log.info(readLine);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        isContentPosted = false;

        log.error("Error While sending HTTP POST request to "+url);
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    } finally {

        post.releaseConnection();
        if (br != null)
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (Exception fe) {
                isContentPosted = false;
                log.error("Error While sending HTTP POST request to "+url);
                log.error(fe.getMessage());
            }
    }
    return isContentPosted;
}
```

Comment: This really sounds like a defect of the service endpoint: Returning no response at all is in clear violation of the RFCs. Oh, and your last check on the response code is a bit off: `if(returnCode >= 200 && returnCode < 300)` is way better than a `match()`

Comment: Thank you. I'll optimize code as per your suggestions :)